# Error en calculo de cambio moneda PHP

Tags: php, sandbox

tengo un problema de matemáticas. Este problema no siempre sucede. A veces hay una diferencia de **1 centavo** entre el *subtotal* y el precio de los productos.
Estoy probando con sandbox.

Mi moneda por defecto es el **euro**, cuando esta activada funciona bien, en cambio si cambio mi moneda a **Colombia** o cualquier país latinoamericano solo funciona en ocasiones, porque hay una diferencia de 1 centavo he observado.

Obtengo estos array para el *buildrequest*.

**Ejemplo de moneda Euro (por defecto): (funciona bien el cálculo)**

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adidas
            [description] => Sudadera Adicolor Classics 3 bandas
            [type] => PHYSICAL
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => EUR
                    [value] => 63.75
                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [category] => PHYSICAL_GOODS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adidas
            [description] => Sudadera Adicolor Classics 3 bandas
            [type] => PHYSICAL
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => EUR
                    [value] => 85.00
                )

            [quantity] => 2
            [category] => PHYSICAL_GOODS
        )

)

Array
(
    [price] => Array
        (
            [subtotal] => 233.75
            [total] => 282.84
            [tax] => 49.09
            [shipping] => 2.50
            [shipping_discount] => 0
            [handling] => 0
            [discount] => 0
            [amount] => 285.34
        )

    [moneda] => Array
        (
            [currency] => EUR
            [locale] => es-ES
        )

)
```

63.75 + 1 cant. = 63.75
85.00 + 2 cant. = 170
El subtotal debe ser: 233.75

Como se puede ver es correcto.

**Veamos un caso con otra moneda y con el fallo del centimo:**

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adidas
            [description] => Sudadera Adicolor Classics 3 bandas
            [type] => PHYSICAL
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => USD
                    [value] => 288110.48
                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [category] => PHYSICAL_GOODS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Adidas
            [description] => Sudadera Adicolor Classics 3 bandas
            [type] => PHYSICAL
            [unit_amount] => Array
                (
                    [currency_code] => USD
                    [value] => 288110.48
                )

            [quantity] => 1
            [category] => PHYSICAL_GOODS
        )

)

Array
(
    [price] => Array
        (
            [subtotal] => 576220.95
            [total] => 685702.93
            [tax] => 109481.98
            [shipping] => 8.50
            [shipping_discount] => 0
            [handling] => 0
            [discount] => 0
            [amount] => 685711.43
        )

    [moneda] => Array
        (
            [currency] => USD
            [locale] => en-CO
        )

)
```

288110.48 + 1 cant. = 288110.48
288110.48 + 1 = 288110.48
El subtotal debe dar: 576.220,96

Como se puede ver, no es correcto, el calculo me dio: `[subtotal] => 576220.95`, y deber ser `576.220,96`.

> ¿Alguien sabe los motivos? He hecho pruebas con round(), ceil(), floor y no logro.

Leí: [Floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)
y [SO: ¿Las matemáticas de punto flotante están rotas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Pero las matematicas no es mi punto fuerte.

Deja las funiones de como se estan creando estos valores.

**Mi codigo:**

Uso **Matemáticas de precisión arbitraria BCMath**

`bcscale(15);`, la escala esta alta en 15.

*Funcion que me retorna los productos para el buildrequest* (array mostrado parte arriba)

```
public static function listaProductos() : array
{
// Set array items.
$items = [];
$instance = new self();
// Load data cart
$cart = $instance->loadShopCart();  

$moneda = UserCurrencySelection::getActive();

// Create items
foreach ($cart as $data) :                              
    // Precio
    $price_excl = $data['precio'];
    // Descuento                        
    $descuento = ($data['descuento'] > 0) ? $data['descuento'] : null;
    // Formateamos precio a moneado local o activo
    $formatPrecio = new Price($price_excl,$descuento);
    // Obtener precio exclusico (sin impuesto)
    $precio_exl =  PriceLocalization::LocalPricePayment($formatPrecio);         
            
    $items[] = [                    
        'name' => $data['info']['marca'],                  
        'description' => $data['info']['titulo'],                   
        'type' => 'PHYSICAL', // PHYSICAL (default)  | DIGITAL  | SERVICE            
        'unit_amount' =>
            [
                'currency_code' => $moneda['moneda'],
                'value' => $precio_exl,
            ],
        'quantity' => $data['cantidad'],
        'category' => 'PHYSICAL_GOODS',
    ];          
endforeach; 
// Items (Array)
return $items;      
}
```

**2. Funcion con la configuracion, subtotal, total, shipping, etc.** (array mostrado parte arriba)

```
public static function configCarro() 
{       
    $instance = new self();
    // Load data cart
    $cart = $instance->loadShopCart();    
    // Comprobar si existe sesion         
    if ($cart) :              
        // Resets            
        $subtotal = 0;                        
        // Recorremos carro de compras
        foreach ($cart as $item) {                                
            // Creamos el total del carro
            //
            // Total cesta
            // No existe descuento en precio, sumamos total sin IVA (sin impuesto)
            if ($item['descuento'] == 0) :    
                $total_excl = bcmul( $item['precio'], $item['cantidad']);                                                           
                // Sum Total
                $subtotal = bcadd($subtotal, $total_excl);                  
            // Si existe descuento, calculamos precio con descuento sin IVA (sin impuesto)
            else :                           
                // Calculamos precio exclusivo con descuento
                //
                // Descuento
                $discount_excl = bcmul($item['precio'], bcmul('0.01', $item['descuento']));// (Multiplica dos números de precisión arbitraria)  
               //var_dump($discount_excl);
                // Aplicar descuento a precio exclusivo 
                $total_excl = bcsub($item['precio'], $discount_excl);// (Resta un número de precisión arbitraria de otro)
                // Multipar el producto por la cantidad
                $total_excl = bcmul( $total_excl, $item['cantidad']);// (Multiplica dos números de precisión arbitraria)                    
                // Sumamos Total                    
                $subtotal = bcadd($subtotal, $total_excl);
            endif;                   
        }
        // Formateamos precio total 
        $formatPrecio = new Price($subtotal);
        // Obtener config pago paypal en moneda local o activo
        $arr =  PriceLocalization::LocalPricePayment($formatPrecio,true);       
        
        return $arr;
    else:
        return [];
        error_log('BuildRequest : Error no se pudo crear sus datos. Ruta: transaccion/PayPal/requestPayPal()');
    endif;         
}
```

**Y realmente la funcion que me hace los calculos es esta:**

```
public static function LocalPricePayment(Price $price, bool $config = false) {
        $currencyinfo = UserCurrencySelection::getActive();
        return static::displayPricePayment($price, $currencyinfo, $config);
}

    /**
     * Realizar la conversión y el formateo real
     *
     * @param Price $price
     * @param array $currencyinfo
     * @param array $style
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function displayPricePayment(Price $price, array $currencyinfo, bool $config) 
{
    // Fetch the original price (and discounts):
    [$value_src, $discount_pct, $discount_active] = $price->getRawValues();
    $is_free             = ($discount_active === 2);
    $is_discount         = ($discount_active   > 0);       

    // Multiply the original price with the conversion rate (`cambio`) to adjust it to this currency (giving us the pre-tax price)
    $value_excl          = bcmul($value_src, $currencyinfo['cambio']);
    $value_excl_wd       = $value_excl; // WD = without discount

    // Calculate the discount
    $discount_excl       = ($is_discount ? bcmul($value_excl, bcmul('0.01', $discount_pct)) : '0.0');
    // Apply the discount to the excl price
    $value_excl          = bcsub($value_excl, $discount_excl);
    // Calculate the tax, by multiplying the adjusted price with the taxrate (`impuesto`*0.01 to adjust for it being a percentage)
    $tax                 = bcmul($value_excl,    bcmul('0.01', $currencyinfo['impuesto']));
    $tax_wd              = bcmul($value_excl_wd, bcmul('0.01', $currencyinfo['impuesto']));
    // Add the tax to the price to get the "price including tax"
    $value_incl          = bcadd($value_excl,    $tax);
    
    //var_dump($value_excl);

    // Dividir si trabjao con enteros (@xerif aqui hago las divisiones de enteros a xxx.xx)
    $value_incl          = bcdiv($value_incl, 100);
    $value_excl          = bcdiv($value_excl, 100);
    $tax          = bcdiv($tax, 100);
    
    // Change the number into human readable form
    $precio_excl = number_format($value_excl, 2, '.', '');
    // Change the number into human readable form
    $precio_incl = number_format($value_incl, 2, '.', '');
    // Change the number into human readable form
    $iva = number_format($tax, 2, '.', '');

    // Gastaos envio y manipulacion
    $shipping = ($currencyinfo['shipping'] > 0) ? $currencyinfo['shipping'] : 0;
    $handling = ($currencyinfo['handling'] > 0) ? $currencyinfo['handling'] : 0;

    // Suma de precio total + envio + manipulacion
    $amount = 0;
    $total_ship = bcadd($value_incl, $shipping);
    $amount = bcadd($total_ship, $handling);
    $amount = number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');

    /**
     * Datos devueltos para configuracion BuildRequest PayPal
     */
    $arr = [];
    if ($config) 
        $arr = [
            'price' => [
                'subtotal' => $precio_excl,
                'total' => $precio_incl,
                'tax' => $iva,
                'shipping' =>  $shipping,
                'shipping_discount' =>  (int) 0,
                'handling' => $handling,
                'discount' => (int) 0,
                'amount' => $amount,
            ],
            'moneda' => [
                'currency' => $currencyinfo['moneda'],
                'locale' => $currencyinfo['locale'],
            ]
        ];

    if ($config) return $arr;
    // Precio devuelto para item
    else return $precio_excl;
    
}
```

El precio la guardo en mi BD como **decimal (10,2)**, en euro seria algo como *85.00*, son precios exclusivos.

Luego la moneda la obtengo desde una cookie algo como:

```
    (
        [id_moneda] => 3
        [moneda] => USD
        [decimals] => 2
        [pais] => Colombia
        [iso] => CO
        [locale] => en-CO
        [cambio] => 4519.38
        [impuesto] => 19
        [currency_symbol] => $
        [decimal_separator] => ,
        [thousands_separator] => .
        [shipping] => 8.50
        [handling] => 0.00
    )
```

¿Se agradece cualquier ayuda? No se el motivo de este fallo, si es como estoy guardando estos datos, o si tengo algun fallo. Ante mano gracias.

**EDIT:**
Aqui tengo la configuracion digamos para el cambio de moneda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT:**

*Añado otra funcion que me formatea los precio que se usa en el codigo:*

```
<?php 
/**
 * Dado que los precios son un valor complejo, formateamos un precio valido 
 */
class Price {
    private $value;           // (string) The regular price such as '1382.95' (without tax, without discount)
    private $discount;        // discount% : 0 means no discount; (int) 1..99 mean x% discount (eg: 60 means 60%); 100 = free/gratis
    private $discount_active; // FALSE = discount-feature not in use; NULL/(int)0: no discount; 1: discount is in effect; 2: discount 100% (eg: free/gratis)

    public function __construct($value, $discount=false) {
        $value = trim((string) $value);
        if (!is_numeric($value) || preg_match('#^(\-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,5})?$#D', $value) !== 1) throw new Exception('Invalid price value');
        $this->value = $value;
        if     (is_null($discount))      { $this->discount = 0; $this->discount_active = NULL; }
        elseif ($discount === false)     { $this->discount = 0; $this->discount_active = FALSE; }
        else {
            $discountInt = (is_numeric($discount) ? (int) $discount : '');
            if ((string) $discountInt !== (string) $discount) throw new Exception('Invalid discount value (should be NULL or Number 0..100 (or FALSE to skip)');
            if     ($discountInt <=   0) { $this->discount =      0; $this->discount_active = 0; }
            elseif ($discountInt >= 100) { $this->discount =    100; $this->discount_active = 2; }
            else { $this->discount = $discountInt; $this->discount_active = 1; }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtener los valores brutos
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRawValues() : array
    {
        return [ $this->value, $this->discount, $this->discount_active ];
    }

    /**
     * Al imprimir un precio (usando echo por ejemplo), imprímalo en su forma convertida (definida más adelante) 
     */
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return PriceLocalization::displayLocalPrice( $this );
    }
}
```

**Edit: Probe cambiar la columna precio a enteros algo como 8500 **

Posterior añadi estas lineas a mis calculos:

```
// Dividir si trabjao con enteros (@xerif aqui hago las divisiones de enteros a xxx.xx)
    $value_incl          = bcdiv($value_incl, 100);
    $value_excl          = bcdiv($value_excl, 100);
    $tax          = bcdiv($tax, 100);
```

Pero me sigue el mismo fallo del fallo de un centimo :(

**Edit:** @OscarGarcia

estuve haciendo todo tipos de pruebas, trabajar con precios con IVA en BD y posterior calcular el *SubTotal y IVA del Total*, y persisten los mismos errores del céntimo, entonces realmente me acorde que, si trabajas con precios sin IVA en la BD, por ejemplo `99.99` en ocasiones daría problemas.

Entonces se me ocurrió para solucionar el problema del cambio de moneda por ejemplo si hago el cambio de moneda y una vez este esté convertido por ejemplo obtengo `$ 92.04`, este se convierte a `92.05` y de esta manera siempre trabajar con números decimales que acaban en `.00` o `.05` o redondear si es mayor a `> 5`. ¿Lo he implementado y al parecer parece que está funcionando, lo vez una buena solución? Digamos `92.02` se convierte en `92.00` y si es `92.03` seria `92.05`, y `92.06` seria `93.00`. La diferencia si no se hace el redondeo, pero con el fallo del céntimo con PayPal son de pocos céntimos aplicando esta regla.

Comment: ¿Por qué no te centras en el problema? Me parece que la pregunta está demasiado difusa. Para empezar, no es posible que el mismo producto cueste `63.75 Euros` y su valor en dólares sea de `288110.48` o sea ***doscientos ochenta y ocho mil ciento diez dólares con cuarenta y ocho centavos***. ¿Cómo explicas esa diferencia de precios?

Comment: @A.Cedano Estaba intentando agregar información para que se entendiera de la mejor manera XD. Pues realmente según tengo yo entendido si yo vendo en España la tasa de impuesto se paga en el país donde el comprador, en este caso el impuesto de España es más alto que el Impuesto de Colombia por ejemplo, entonces calculo sobre precio exclusivo el cambio de moneda y luego la tasa de impuesto según el país. Tuve un problema anterior y me contestaron en OP, y lo implementi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477765/format-money-number-format-php

Comment: Ya, pero la diferencia entre dólares y euros no es tan grande. Y yo veo que la respuesta indica que el precio es en dólares, pero hablas también de pesos colombianos, lo cual es confuso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Te voy a añadir a mi respuesta la tabla que uso para el cambio de monedas, aun así, no entiendo porque a veces si funciona y otra no porque hay un fallo de 1 céntimo, como se puede observar en las primeros array de mi pregunta. Realmente es un poco confuso esto del cambio de moneda.

Comment: @A.Cedano por ejemplo si el cambio de moneda la pongo a *1.13* dolares, entonces *77,14* € me da $ *85,72*, estos valores lo manejo facilmente desde la BD, realmente es algo que me confunde, ya que como me has mencionado hay peso colombiano y dolares, al igual para mas paises latino americano. Entonces si uso en-CO deberia aplicar la conversion a dolares 1.13 o a pesos colombianos 4519.38? De hecho si pongo a dolares la conversion (1.13) funciona mejor, pero sigue fallando en ocaciones.

Comment: El problema del céntimo seguramente se deba al hecho de trabajar con flotantes en lugar de enteros y su perdida de precisión, échale un vistazo a https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.float.php

Comment: @Xerif he cambiado los precios a ```int``` que sería *85* y me sigue saliendo el fallo en ocasiones me falla un céntimo. He cambiado las matemáticas de *Funciones de BC Math* a lo tradicional y me sigue pasando lo mismo. Hay que recordar que solo pasa cuando se hace el cambio de la moneda. Entonces no se si una vez se calcula el cambio hay que hacer algo diferente, he intentado también ```floatval(round($precio,2);``` y nada. Si alguien sabe cómo se debe calcular un cambio de moneda, sin fallos de céntimos se agradece.

Comment: Pero cuando hablo de trabajar con enteros es hacerlo con céntimos. Por ejemplo en lugar de 85.72€ tendrás 8572 centimos de €. Luego cuando termines de realizar todas las operaciones matematicas lo vuelves a convertir a € dividiendo entre 100

Comment: @Xerif ahora entiendo, voy a probar lo que me comentas, modificando mi sistema, hare un backup, aunque una duda, por ejemplo cuando se hace un cálculo sobre el impuesto y el número es **entero** será en este caso *8572* me daría ```10.372,12``` , me volvería los números flotantes, este cálculo si sería precisa?

Comment: @Xerif he hecho pruebas con números enteros (*8500*), y antes de devolver los valores a mi *buildrequest* hago un ```$value_incl = bcdiv($value_incl, 100);``` y me sigue dando el fallo de un céntimo, me devuelve el mismo resultado de si uso decimal() en la BD. A ver si más tarde actualizo mejor mi respuesta, porque me gustaría resolver este tema.

Comment: Un apunte por si te es de ayuda. En los departamentos de gestión económica/financiera no se hace la conversión de moneda elemento a elemento en una factura, si no que ésta se calcula del total de la misma. Es el método más eficaz para evitar arrastrar en exceso o defecto decimales ocultos. De modo que no te recomiendo hacer conversión de moneda de cada uno de los elementos. Si insistes en hacerlo hazlo partiendo del total (es decir, calcula los impuestos del total y no de la conversión de moneda).

Comment: @OscarGarcia es un buen detalle que no sabía, pero entonces como lo calculan, cuando te refieras del total, digamos precio total inclusive impuestos ya añadido? ¿y después calculo el cambio de moneda? ¿Y para los items seria me imagino lo mismo, primero calculo precio inclusive y después el cambio de moneda? Digamos 85.00 + 21% IVA = 102.85 €, seria hacer el cambio aquí 1.13 * 112.85 + 1% del fallo que pueda tener

Comment: @OscarGarcia luego otra duda y es donde tengo el fallo, realmente es confuso este tema, digamos a PayPal le tengo que pasar los productos de la venta, estos deben ser sin tasas (IVA), ya que se añade en *'tax_total' =>*, entonces esos precios deben tener el cambio de moneda también. Y esta suma tiene que cuadrar con el *subtotal*. Y allí es donde tengo el fallo del céntimo. también he observado que a veces puede estar en la suma de subtotal + taxes = amount

Comment: Me estaba alargando en el tema, el tamaño de los comentarios es corto, de modo que te recomiendo que [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132714/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-dbe).

Comment: @OscarGarcia he añadido un **Edit** al final de mi respuesta para ti, sino es muy largo aquí de comentario para explicarme, a ver qué te parece?

Comment: La forma correcta de calcular el valor de dos de los tres valores (total, IVA y neto) a partir de uno de ellos es calcular únicamente uno de los restantes y despejar de la siguiente fórmula: total = neto + IVA. Ejemplo: Si tienes un total de 100 (moneda), el neto es 82,64 (moneda) y el IVA 100 - 82,64 = 17,35 (moneda). **No hagas la conversión de cada elemento a la nueva moneda**, calcula los otros dos a partir de uno de ellos. (por norma general, del total, por ser el valor mayor y, por lo tanto, el que arrastra un menor error de conversión/redondeo).

Comment: @OscarGarcia también hice lo que me comentas, poner los precios con IVA en BD y posterior calcular el subtotal y IVA sobre el precio total, pero en el sistema de PayPal al finalizar el pago muestro el precio de los productos sin IVA * cantidad, entonces esa suma sigue fallando con el subtotal, aunque lo calculo con esa regla. Voy a intentar adoptar mi Clase, y calcular todo en un proceso como mencionas, a ver si así salen dichos cálculos  envede por separado. También he visto que PayPal permite pasar precios con IVA y simplemente pones el total sin poner IVA ni subtotal, seria otra opción.